# Behaviour of solutions of a differential system at bifurcation values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What are the local and global behavior of solutions of

$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}r'&=r−r^2\\
\theta'&=(\sin\theta /2)^2+a\end{array}\right.$$
at all bifurcation values?